# Bifurcation analysis (Jacobian) of system of ODEs with time-dependent terms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, jacobian, bifurcation

How can I perform a bifurcation analysis for a dynamical system of ODEs that has time-varying terms?

For example consider the ODE:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)+\nu(t)$$
where $\nu(t)$ is an additive term that depends on time $t$.

Is it possible to compute the Jacobian matrix to determine whether the system is critical and to determine the nature of the bifurcation? How would one compute the Jacobian for such systems? What are other options to perform a bifurcation analysis of such a system?

Comment: The eigenvalues of the Jacobian will not help you in determining the stability of the system (not even for a linear time variant system). It would help if you could provide the ODEs.

Comment: ODEs added. How could I find out (a) if the system is critical and (b) the bifurcation?

Comment: Please typeset the equations in Mathjax. If you picture link expires, it will not be possible in the future to see them.

Comment: I added a typeset equation. The precise equations are basically irrelevant, the answer should apply to systems of ODEs in general. You write the eigenvalues of the Jacobian will not help. Why is that so? What would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of continuous dynamical system is non-autonomous. One can write equivalently
$$
\frac{d}{dt}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
\tau
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
f(x) + \nu(\tau)\\
1
\end{array}
\right) ,
$$
which is of the form $d y/dt = g(y)$ with $y = (x,\tau)^\top$. In the case where $\nu$ is a periodic function, the [Melnikov method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melnikov_distance) is a dedicated tool for this type of system.

Comment: It can be noted that this "state space" does not have any equilibria because $\dot{\tau}=1≠0$. So in this formulation there are no bifurcations, since the number or stability of equilibria does not change. But Melnikov assumes a periodic $\nu(\tau)$. So one can use discrete stability analysis after one period in order to say something about bifurcations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Harry and Kwin, this is very helpful!